# How to write Junit test cases for spring boot application?

Tags: java, junit, entity

I have to write some junit test cases to check entity. I'm using postgres as my database.

My entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "display")
public class Display {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String title;
private String group;

public Display() {

}
public Display(Long id, String title, String grp) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title= title;  
    this.group= grp;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setGroup(String id) {
    this.group = id;
}

public String getGroup() {
    return this.group;
}

public void settitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String gettitle() {
    return this.title;
}

}
```

My repository

```
@Repository
public interface DisplayRepository extends CrudRepository<Display, Long> {

}
```

Interface

```
public interface IDisplayService {
    List<Display> findAll();
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class DisplayService implements IDisplayService {
    @Autowired
    private DisplayRepository repository;

@Override
public List<Display> findAll() {
    List<Display> d = (List<Display>) repository.findAll();
    return d;
}
}
```

I tried writing junit test cases but I get Could'nt load Application. Whats the right way to write junit test cases for this?

This is the test case I wrote for service

folder : test/java/example/demo/Test.java

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:conn.properties")

public class DisplayServiceTest {


@Value("${id}")
private String value;


@Mock
private DisplayRepository DisplayReps;

@InjectMocks
private DisplayService DisplayService;

@Test
public void whenFindAll_thenReturnProductList() {

Menu m = new Menu()
m.setId(value);

    List<Display> expectedDisplay = Arrays.asList(m);
    doReturn(expectedDisplay).when(DisplayReps).findAll();
    List<Display> actualDisplay = DisplayService.findAll();
    assertThat(actualDisplay).isEqualTo(expectedDisplay);
}
```

in test/java/example/demo/resources
    conn.properties
    id=2

Its returning 0 for value
Whats the issue?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the test class you created? Did you annotated the class to run with SpringRunner? You may also want to add @SpringBootTest. Look also here for a tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Comment: I have updated my post with test case

Comment: Use HSQL or H2 DB as Proxy DB

Comment: The DisplayRepository stores `Menus`. Please post that class.

Comment: Its display class itself not Menus. Can someone write a demo test class and explain?

Comment: Did you try to remove AutoConfigureTestDatabase and run the test, again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to make your code to work. I will post only the changed classes:

The interface:

```
public interface DisplayRepository extends CrudRepository<Display, Long> {

   Optional<Display> findByTitle(String name);
}
```

The test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DataJpaTest
public class DisplayRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

@Autowired
private DisplayRepository productRespository;

@Before()
public void setUp(){

    Display m = new Display();
    // m.setId(2L); // The ID is autogenerated; can retrieve it from the persistAndFlush result
    m.setCategory("Group1");
    m.setTitle("Product2");

    testEntityManager.persistAndFlush(m);
}

@Test
public void whenFindByName_thenReturnProduct() {
    // when
    Display product = productRespository.findByTitle("Product2").orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Product not found"));

    // then
    assertThat(product.getTitle()).isEqualTo("Product2");
}

@Test
public void whenFindAll_thenReturnProductList() {
    // when
    List<Display> products = (List<Display>) productRespository.findAll();

    // then
    assertThat(products).hasSize(1);
}
}
```

When trying to run the code you provided, there were a few issues:

- you were using the reserved word `group` as a field in the Display class. Because of this, Hibernate couldn't create the table, so I renamed it to category.
- there was a compilation issue because the method `findByName` wasn't defined in the repository; also, there was no field `name` in the Display class to which the mapping to be made; because of this, I've added the method `findByTitle` because it's an existing field and it seemed to match the value you queried in the test method.
- because the ID field is autogenerated, the test setup() failed when persisting the Display.

If you want to use @Mock for mocking classes, you must call:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

You can then mock responses as usual: `Mockito.when(DisplayReps.findByTitle("A")).thenReturn(Optional.of(new Display(2L, "ALFA", "GRP1")));`

Comment: I tried this but now I'm getting SQL error telling ERROR: column "category" is of  type integer but expression is of type character varying. but category is of string value only. I dont know why it's showing integer.

Comment: I've tested with a H2 DB. Can you switch to it to see if the code runs? In case you are using an existing DB instance, maybe you should drop the table for the Display and try again or configure Hibernate to drop the tables `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` (only while running this tests).

Comment: Hey I have updated the unit test. Can you tell me whats wrong with that? If I manually enter id as 2 it will work but through properties file it wont work

Comment: You should run the test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. The way you had it set, Spring didn't try to load it's context and the config was ignored.

Comment: I've edited the response. Please mark the question as answered because you are starting to ask other thing unrelated to the original question and you should make new questions for them.